# Span not showing in image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image slider and I completely changed the Jquery of it to use less code and I cannot figure out why my `cycle-pager` is not showing up.

You can see on my original slider the `cycle-pager` at the bottom/center of the image: http://realtorcatch.com/slider3

In addition, I feel that this new slider doesn't have as smooth of a transition. Is there anything I could do to make it more smooth or just in general make it better?

```js
$(".slider_img").filter(":gt(0)").each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
$(".image_text").filter(":gt(0)").each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

current = 0;
limit = $(".slider_img").length;

$(".cycle-prev").click(function() {

  current--;

  if (current < 0) {
    current = 2;
  }

  $($(".slider_img").hide().get(current)).fadeIn(1000);
  $($(".image_text").hide().get(current)).fadeIn(1000);
});

$(".cycle-next").click(function() {
  current++;

  if (current >= 3) {
    current = 0;
  }

  $($(".slider_img").hide().get(current)).fadeIn(1000);
  $($(".image_text").hide().get(current)).fadeIn(1000);

});

setInterval(function() {
  $(".cycle-next").click();
}, 5000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
.slider_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*height: 60vh;*/
  /*height: 100vh;*/
}
.cycle-slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.image_text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 35%;
}
.cycle-prev,
.cycle-next {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cycle-prev {
  left: 10%;
}
.cycle-next {
  right: 10%;
}
.cycle-pager {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cycle-pager span {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
​
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
  <span class="image_text">Travelling has never been easier</span>
  <span class="image_text">The Beach</span>
  <span class="image_text">Space is amazing</span>
  <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
  <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
  <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
  <img class="slider_img" src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/subway2.jpg" alt="subway">
  <img class="slider_img" src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/beach2.jpg" alt="beach">
  <img class="slider_img" src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/space2.jpg" alt="space">
</div>
```

Comment: The `<span class="cycle-pager"></span>` doesn't have any content in them?

Comment: Right. That is how my original plugin was. Here is that code, but you can see in the fiddle it does not show for some reason, but on my site it does... https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Dy0xqbRVSy

Comment: Your fiddle link is obsolete. Lemme check your site.

Comment: It works perfectly in your site, so what's the problem now?

Comment: I re-created the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ia3xOi8M90

Comment: Nopes. That again is an empty link.

Comment: @PraveenKumar My issue is, the code that is on my site is the plugin style, in which I am unable to get the text to transition because I added it on after. The new code allows the text to transition.

Comment: Does this work now? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ia3xOi8M90 . Not sure why it isn't working for you. I don't like the new jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is **showing up** on the view, but it is invisible because:

```
<span class="cycle-pager"></span>
```

The above is the state, even after rendering is done. You need to set some value to make it visible by using:

```
$(".cycle-pager").text("Something...");
```

There's nothing in your JavaScript, that has either `$(".cycle-pager").html()` or `$(".cycle-pager").text()`.

**Update**

The only near-perfect to your answer I can come up with is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').bxSlider();
});
```

```css
.slide {position: relative;}
.slide img {display: block; max-width: 100%;}
.slide span {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 65%; text-align: center; width: 100%;}
.bx-controls.bx-has-controls-direction.bx-has-pager {margin-top: -50px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar1">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar1"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar2">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar2"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar3">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar3"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar4">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar4"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar5">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar5"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar6">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar6"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar7">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar7"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar8">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar8"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar9">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar9"!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x1500&text=FooBar10">
    <span>My Text for "FooBar10"!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.cycle-pager {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
height:110px;

}
.cycle-pager span {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
color:#fff;


}
```

http://codepen.io/markware/pen/wMJGgq

You are missing height in your absolute  .cycle-pager span

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. `:(`

Comment: yes you are right :) , i really thought styling was the probem